# Trigger is not updating Checkbox

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a object credit request which has records added to it from object credit line.  The following trigger should update the field on the credit request object, when credit lines are added, deleted or updated and certain criteria is met.  Currently the checkbox does not update.  Looking for a second set of eyes.

```
    trigger MakingApprovalRequiredTrigger on Credit_Lines__c (After Insert, After Update, After Delete){

    List<Id> parentIds = new List<Id>();

    If(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){
        For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.New){
            If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
                parentIds.add(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
            }
        }
    }


    If(Trigger.IsDelete){
        For(Credit_Lines__c crdLine : Trigger.Old){
            If(crdLine.Credit_Request__c != Null){
                parentIds.add(crdLine.Credit_Request__c);
            }
        }
    }

    List<Credit_Request__c> parentFinalList = New List<Credit_Request__c>();
    Double d = 0.00;

    For(Credit_Request__c crdReq : [Select Id, Approval_Required__c,
                                            (Select Id, Quantity__c, Product__c FROM Credit_Lines__r) 
                                                                        FROM Credit_Request__c 
                                                                                WHERE Id =: parentIds])
    {
        d = 0.00;
        Set<String> ProductCodes = New Set<String>();

        For(Credit_Lines__c EveryChild : crdReq.Credit_Lines__r )
        {
            d += EveryChild.Quantity__c;
            ProductCodes.add(String.valueOf(EveryChild.Product__c));
        }


            If(d >= 0.5 && ProductCodes.Contains('100-171-800'))
            {
                crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
            }
            else If(d > 0.00 && ProductCodes.Contains('101-008-000'))
            {
                crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
                parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
            }

    }
    try{
        If(!parentFinalList.IsEmpty()){
            update parentFinalList;
        }
    }
    Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception Thrown For MakingApprovalRequired Is:: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your record match the if criteria. and `Quantity__c` will not equal to null.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your provided code. Are you getting any error messages? Have you checked your debug log to see if your DML update is running into any exceptions?

Comment: Thanks no alarms, was product__c was pulling the id.  The checkbox updates when criteria is met, but if I make changes after the checkbox is updated, the trigger does not uncheck the box.  I thought the after update and after delete would uncheck the box if criteria is not met.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about now. Checkboxes behave like any other field. By that, I mean that the value won't change unless you explicitly tell it to (manually through the detail page, or automatically through a trigger/workflow field update/process builder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, this trigger is working to 'check' the checkbox (i.e. set its value to `true`) when your criteria is met. The part you're having issues with here is to have your trigger also 'uncheck' the checkbox when a particular record doesn't meet your set criteria.

Checkboxes, like any other (non-formula) field, don't automatically update themselves. You need to explicitly tell Salesforce to do that for you via a trigger, workflow rule field update, or process builder (scheduled/batch apex or anonymous apex via the developer console would also work).

The key part that's missing in your trigger right now is in this portion of your code

```
If(d >= 0.5 && ProductCodes.Contains('100-171-800'))
{
    crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
}
else If(d > 0.00 && ProductCodes.Contains('101-008-000'))
{
    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
    parentFinalList.add(crdReq );
}
```

You set `Approval_Required__c` to true in those two cases, but you don't have any code that sets `crdreq.Approval_Required__c = false;`, and you don't have code to do something when both of your existing conditions aren't satisfied.

The simple fix here would be to just add an `else` block to your existing code

```
// Since parentFinalList.add appears in all branches of this if/elseif/else,
//   that line can be taken out.
// Doing so makes your code more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), which is generally
//   a good thing.
If(d >= 0.5 && ProductCodes.Contains('100-171-800'))
{
    crdReq.Approval_Required__c = true;
}
else If(d > 0.00 && ProductCodes.Contains('101-008-000'))
{
    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = true;
}
else
{
    crdreq.Approval_Required__c = false;
}

parentFinalList.add(crdReq);
```

Comment: Thanks that took care of it and it is working.  Now I have a new issue.  I have a trigger on credit_request__c that automatically adds credit lines with quantity based on a multiplier field.  This works.  The trigger above also works now on its own.  But if I allow the credit_request trigger to populate the credit lines, even if the quantity is below my threshold.  The approval check box still updates.  The credit request has the following calucation   Quantity__c = (a.Qty__c * multiplier).  Not sure why the check box is check if this value is below the criteria.